Nikon d810 preset White balance turning yellowish outdoor
When taking outdoor pictures with my nikon d810 and using preset manual white balance, the results are not okay, and it turns out yellowish even though I do everything correctly.
It works fine with indoor photography, though.
Does anyone know what to do to fix this??

Are you setting the custom white balance indoors and then using the same CWB outside? Or creating a second CWB outside?

I create a new custem white balance outside. I tried both ways to take a picture of a white sheet then select it in preset and to long press wb so the camera itself take information from the white sheet.

Personally I would not use just a plain white sheet of paper for this. Personally I'd use something like a WhiBal or an ExpoDisc.

If the sheet has been washed in certain laundry detergents it will reflect a disproportionate amount of UV/near UV light that could throw the WB off. Correcting for the blue cast of the sheet would make everything else have an amber/yellow cast.

A preset manual white balance will only be appropriate for the exact lighting for which you set it. If you move to a different location with different lighting (or indeed if you even just move the camera to a different position under the same lighting), that white balance setting is no longer appropriate.

I don't move the camera to different lighting or position. I keep the white sheet exacly where my subject is، also the position of the camera is fixed because I use it with a tripod.

The sheet may be the same, but the light falling on the sheet and being reflected to the camera when outdoors is considerably different than the light falling on the sheet when indoors. Custom white balance adjustments are made to compensate for the different light in each shooting environment.
